# How to get song info on Azuracast from another domain?

Tags: javascript, cross-origin-resource-policy

I want to get some song info from my Azuracast IP such as the album art, song name, and the artist. The Azuracast API allows you to get this info from the URL: http://your-ip/api/nowplaying and it returns a JSON file. I want to get this info and put it on an HTML element via JavaScript. It says this: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-ip/' from origin 'http://my-domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've tried it but nothing worked.

```
function stats() {
  $.getJSON('https://ip-here/', (data) => {
    console.log(data.now_playing.song.artist);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://ip-here/', true);
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

I get the error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-ip/' from origin 'http://my-domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: If you can't alter the server config you  might need [crossorigin](https://github.com/connorhudson/crossorigin.me) to work as a proxy to allow you cross origin via javascript.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it a little easier? I'm not so good at this stuff.

Comment: you can try `$.getJSON('https://crossorigin.me/https://ip-here/'`  the owner of crossorigin allow you to cross origin while `https://my-ip/` won't allow you to to access data from another origin.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: @xianshenglu It says this: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://infinityfree.net/errors/404/ with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: Might because the api you provided is not return a json while you used `$.getJSON`. Maybe you can try `$.getJSON('https://crossorigin.me/http://your-ip/api/nowplaying'`